# Create new .txt file with specific input from two different .txt files in Python

Tags: python, text, replace, text-files

For my research I analyse multiple .txt files that look like this:

```
   participant  content
   1    Okay, what are we doing?
   2    Umm, I think that's the equipment shed I'm looking at right now
   2    I'm gonna go to that and see how many tools I can get out
   1    Okay
   2    Um, do you see what I'm talking about?
   1    Yeah
   etc ...
```

The files include a conversation between participants that form a dyad. Every file has a filename like this: dyadx-condA.txt (for example: dyad3-condA.txt) which participant is speaking is indicated with a 1 or 2 under participant. **For my baseline model I want speakers from different dyads coupled together and create a sample of new dyads from there. For example: The content of participant 1 from dyad3-condA.txt with the content of participant 2 from dyad9-condA.txt . This then has to be saved in a new .txt file** The new files need the same make up as the old files, a .txt file with a participant and a content column.It doesn't matter from which dyad participant 1 or 2 is included.

As an example this file dyad16-condA:

```
   participant  content
   1    Hello my name is Joe
   2    Nice to meet you Joe
   2    My name is Marie
   1    Nice to meet you Marie
```

plus this file dyad33-condA:

```
   participant  content
   1    I am tired.
   2    How come?
   1    Because I didn't sleep.
   2    Bummer.
```

make this file dyadx-condA:

```
    participant  content
    1    Hello my name is Joe
    2    How come?
    1    Nice to meet you Marie
    2    Bummer.
```

Now for the programming. How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Whats the requirement for in which order the sentences are in the merged file? or is it pure random?

Comment: I think the best way to go would be using the order of one of the two files. So the order of the file where participant 1 is extracted from would be good!